# How to get previous record date for a group in a select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, msbi

I need to calculate the `Prevdate` as shown below without using CTE or temp tables. I tried using lead it applied for only one row above. Also the number of record for each group might vary. Can anyone suggest a solution here?

Below is the sample data:

```
create table #Sampledata 
(
id int
,groupno int
,Date date
)
insert into #Sampledata values (
1,1,'1/2/2020'),
(2,2,'1/13/2020'),
(3,2,'1/13/2020'),
(4,2,'1/13/2020'),
(5,3,'1/24/2020')
```

Below is the expected output:

[image]

Comment: Post any data and query in the question itself as *text*. Images can't be copied and executed. We can't guess what kind of grouping you want either. Post sample data, the desired output and what you tried.

Comment: You posted an image, not data. Images can't be copied and queried. Don't force people to type all that just to test it, wasting time typing instead of trying different queries.

Comment: How are you trying to calculate the PrevDate field?  You want the last date from the group that's group # n-1?  That's at least the best I can infer from that image.

Comment: Sorry. here is the sample table.
create table #Sampledata 
(
id int
,groupno int
,Date date
)
insert into #Sampledata values (
1,1,'1/2/2020'),
(2,2,'1/13/2020'),
(3,2,'1/13/2020'),
(4,2,'1/13/2020'),
(5,3,'1/24/2020')

Comment: Im not sure how to bring the "PrevDate" field in a select query that's where i face difficulty.

Comment: I have edited the post. Hope my question is clear now.

Comment: Looks more like nextdate to me. How is 13 Jan previous to 2 jan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are calling the previous date is really the next date.  That just helps understanding the question.

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not fully support `range` window frames, so window functions (at least in a simple manner) are not appropriate.

One method is using `lead()` in an aggregation subquery and joining the results in:

```
select sd.*, g.next_date
from sampledata sd join
     (select groupno, lead(min(date)) over (order by groupno) as next_date
      from Sampledata
      group by groupno
     ) g
     on sd.groupno = g.groupno;
```

Another option is `cross apply`:

```
select sd.*, x.next_date
from sampledata sd outer apply
     (select top (1) min(sd2.date) as next_date
      from sampledata sd2
      where sd2.date > sd.date
     ) x;
```

Of course, if the groups really are sequentially enumerated, you can replace `sd2.date > sd.date` with `sd2.groupno = sd.groupno + 1`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bd2d4677f1abf52cb631dcdf3d9da741) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

try joining with one reduced this works only if groupno is continued.

```
select distinct s1.* , s2.PrevDate
from #Sampledata as s1
left join (
select groupno - 1 as num , [Date] as PrevDate
from #Sampledata 
) as s2 on s1.groupno = s2.num
```

Edit: I caused a cartesian explosion so I just rammed a distinct in there to sort it out

[image]

Comment: "I caused a cartesian explosion so I just rammed a distinct in there to sort it out" ?

Comment: This solution assumes that groupno are continuous.